# CefSharp application not responding for a while if internet connection suddenly lost

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, cefsharp

Im using CefSharp with our WPF Application as a web browser and everything seems to be working fine, till when we are trying to stress test the limits of the application (e.g disconnecting internet while on a webpage) when we are almost always experiencing not responding app when we disconnect internet and interact with a wpf button that will be responsible for popping up some UI that shows "No internet connection". Any handler for this? or how can we prevent this? This happens only if there is no internet conenction. I am using CefSharp version 57 btw.

Comment: Version 57 is old and unsupported. How does version 83 behave? You can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for testing purposes

Comment: Will try to check. Thanks

Comment: Hello, I tried it with version 83.4.20.0 and still experiencing some lag/no responding (when user clicks multiple times at the moment it lags) if internet connection is gone..But seems to be fine when connection was not disturbed.

Comment: As CefSharp is one of just many Chromium Embedded wrappers it's best to move the discussion to it's support forum at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php post a link back here and I'll comment if I have anything relevant to add. I'm wondering if you might need to change the online/offline status when the network is connected/disconnected (which can be done via devtools).